# Not able to access state value with dynamic key in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-typescript

```
    let [radioData, setRadioData] = React.useState({
      ActivityStatus: {
        Active: true,
        Inactive: false,
        Completed: false,
      },
      Other: {}
    })

    let options = [{ "label": "Active" }, { "label": "Inactive" }, { "label": "Completed" }]
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {options.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <FormControlLabel
              control={
                <Checkbox
                  checked={radioData.ActivityStatus[item.label]}
                  name="gilad" />
              }
              label={item.label}
            />
          )
        })}
      </div>
    );
```

I am getting the following error if i am trying to access the checked values

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ Active: boolean; Inactive: boolean; Completed: boolean; }'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ Active: boolean; Inactive: boolean; Completed: boolean; }'.

Comment: may be try to remove double quotes from keys options

Comment: @NaolChala tried it, it is still the same

Comment: or try adding double quotes to radioData keys, I don't know if it works but try it

Answer (score 1):

You should define `string` as the type for the keys of the object like this:

```
    import "./styles.css";
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import React from 'react';
export default function App() {
  let [radioData, setRadioData] = React.useState<{[key:string]: boolean | any}>({
    ActivityStatus: {
      "Active": true,
      "Inactive": false,
      "Completed": false,
    },
    Other: {}
  })

  let options = [{ "label": "Active" }, { "label": "Inactive" }, { "label": "Completed" }]
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {options.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Checkbox
              checked={radioData.ActivityStatus[item.label]}
              name="gilad"
              onChange={() => 
                {
                  setRadioData({...radioData,
                     ActivityStatus: 
                     {...radioData.ActivityStatus,
                       [item.label]: !radioData.ActivityStatus[item.label]}})
                      }
                    } />
          }
          label={item.label}
        />
        )
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Check it working [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-bohr-e8ncn?file=/src/App.tsx).

Comment: How do i set state on change if i am updating one value in Acvtivity Status

Comment: I have updated the answer and the sandbox. Do check it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have the ActivityStatus object as a react state, as it seems it is constant. Instead, hold the status key in your objects as necessary, and let ActivityStatus be a constant final dictionary.
I have created a [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-mayer-vmqrk?file=/src/App.tsx) with a minimal reproduicble similar issue. Take a look at it.

Basically I have:

```
const ActivityStatus =  {
  Active : true,
  Inactive : false,
  Completed : false,
}
```

And I keep the status field in the object itself.